# How to let someone login with another account, even though he is already logged in with one account?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

First: Why is this necessary? Why not make people log out first? Because my app automatically creates a new account, when people who aren't logged in open it.

I tried this code:

```
  def create
    current_user.signout
    super
  end
```

But it doesn't work. I don't even know what doesn't work, as I don't get any errors.

I'm using devise.

Answer (score 0):

You need to find the current user first and also define a `signout` action.

Without more information a basic example would be (this is assuming a lot of things):

```rb
def create
  current_user = User.find(params[:id]) # you need to pass the ID to the create action somehow
  current_user.signout
end
```

```rb
# User model (user.rb)
  def signout
    # signout logic goes here
  end
```

Comment: This is all defined by devise. I tagged it "devise" but I should have mentioned in the question that I used devise.